React-Select Custom Component Not Working With Input
I'm working on creating a custom component for React-Select that adds a button to the options.
const customSingleValue = ({ data }) => (
   <div className="custom-single-value">
      <span> {data.label} </span>
      <button>Click me</button>
   </div>
);

<Select
   className="dropdown"
   options={fruitOptions}
   components={{ SingleValue: customSingleValue }}
/>

However, I'm having trouble integrating this with React-Select's input/search feature. The button appears on a separate line, but I want it to stay on the same line as the input/search. Additionally, I want the base functionality of the custom component to be overwritten/hidden by the input/search when the user starts typing.

Question: How can I ensure my custom component stays on the same line as the input/search and is replaced by the input/search when the user starts typing, same as the default behavior?
Full Code:
import Select from "react-select";

const DropdownTest = () => {
    const fruitOptions = [
        { value: 'apple', label: 'Apple' },
        { value: 'banana', label: 'Banana' },
        { value: 'cherry', label: 'Cherry' },
        { value: 'date', label: 'Date' },
        { value: 'fig', label: 'Fig' }
    ];

    const customSingleValue = ({ data }) => (
        <div className="custom-single-value">
            <span> {data.label} </span>
            <button>Click me</button>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div className="dropdown-container">
            <Select
                className="dropdown"
                options={fruitOptions}
                components={{ SingleValue: customSingleValue }}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
export default DropdownTest;


Utilize props to pass in existing information. You can also utilize children instead of data.
const customSingleValue = ({...props}) => (
        <components.SingleValue {...props}>
            <div className="custom-single-value">
                {props.children}
                {/* <span>{props.getValue()[0].label} </span> */}
                <button>Click me</button>
            </div>
        </components.SingleValue>
    );


To achieve this with react-select, you need to make sure your custom component integrates smoothly with the built-in input/search functionality. Your current setup is almost correct, but there are a few things you can change to make sure the button stays on the same line as the input/search and disappears when the user starts typing.
Try this:


import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const DropdownTest = () => {
    const fruitOptions = [
        { value: 'apple', label: 'Apple' },
        { value: 'banana', label: 'Banana' },
        { value: 'cherry', label: 'Cherry' },
        { value: 'date', label: 'Date' },
        { value: 'fig', label: 'Fig' }
    ];

    const CustomSingleValue = ({ data }) => (
        <div className="custom-single-value">
            <span>{data.label}</span>
            <button>Click me</button>
        </div>
    );

    const customStyles = {
        singleValue: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
        }),
        placeholder: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'none', 
        }),
        input: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            margin: 0,
        }),
        control: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
        }),
    };

    return (
        <div className="dropdown-container">
            <Select
                className="dropdown"
                options={fruitOptions}
                components={{ SingleValue: CustomSingleValue }}
                styles={customStyles}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default DropdownTest;



This will make sure that your custom button appears alongside the selected value when an option is selected but does not interfere with the default input and search functionality.
